# Expansion-panel from material angular 4

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I hava an angular 4.4.4 application with `material 2.0.0-beta.12` and I want to use the `mat-expansion-panel` from material design.

This is my code :

```
           <mat-expansion-panel class="parametersPanel">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            PARAMETERS
                        </mat-panel-title>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="parameterListItem">
                                <td class="icon"><img src="assets/images/alert.png"></td>
                                <td class="parameterName">Parameter 1</td>
                                <td class="parameterValue">Value</td>
                                <td class="unit">unit</td>
                            </tr>                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
```

So it works well but it possible to remove the margin in the `mat-expansion-panel-body` which has, from the browser `margin: 0 24px 16px;` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `style.css` or your components style you need to add the following css:

```
/deep/ .parametersPanel .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is due to view encapsulation. You can read more about this here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

**Update:**

The use of `/deep/`, `::ng-deep` to modify the styles of material components has been deprecated. See this [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

However, using `@angular/core` `^6.1.0` and `@angular/material` `^6.4.6` I was able to change the style of Angular Material's Expansion panel without having to add anything specific. It seems like you can now simply change the style in your components css file. So this should work:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can read here for more information about the deprecation of `/deep/`, `::ng-deep` [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working. I have yet the margin in the panel body.

Comment: Where did you add the styling? I added it to `app.component.css` and it worked. You could also try using `padding: 0 !important;`

Comment: I added it the css file from the component and in the `app.component.css` and the both don't work, even with `!important`.

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with the version of Angular and Angular Material you use? Can you also add the css rules that are applied to the `mat-expansion-panel-body` in your browser? For example, i have `padding: 0 24px 16px;`, so if you have `margin: 0 24px 16px;` then you need to replace `padding: 0;` in my solution with `margin: 0;`

Comment: I edited my question with the versions I use. In the browser I can see that `mat-expansion-panel-body` has `margin: 0 24px 16px;`. So, I tested your answer with `margin: 0 !important` and it doesn't work. I also tried with `padding`, it's always the same.

Comment: Ok, your answer is almost right. It's not \deep\ but  /deep/ and it works.
I let you edit your answer !
Thanks again !

Comment: This solution (with :ng-deep, /deep/ and >>>) is going to be deprecated and removed. What solution do we have beside of these?

Comment: @Burnee - I read a blog on ::ngdeep that says the Angular team is using it until a replacement is found at which point they will have to find a work-around themselves. This is the best answer I have found so will use ngdeep until they say otherwise.

Comment: .mat-expansion-panel-body is not within your component, and styles you define in component will only apply to it when view encapsulation is turned off for the component. Otherwise put to a global styles file, not inside a component.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of `/deep/` you should use `::ng-deep`, which is an alias provided by angular. Support for `/deep/` etc. is already removed from chrome browser. So in your example that would be:

```
::ng-deep .parametersPanel .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me inside the component. Just had to add "!important;"

Answer (score 20):

This works 100%.

Add this inside your style.css:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-content > .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: `.mat-expansion-panel-content > .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}` in main styles.css of Angular project, without `important!` works great :) Thanks

Answer (score 11):

this one worked for me

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

I hope that will work for you

Comment: Worked for me @angular/material 8.1.4

Comment: It works, but from now every child componets from this component will be styled alike this, which is unwanted

Comment: This worked for more specific selection: `::ng-deep .your-panel-class > .mat-expansion-panel-content > .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0 !important;
}`

Answer (score 9):

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you add it to the main styles.scss it works (not at the component style level)

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below will work when added to your components css file

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-expansion-panel-spacing {
      margin: 0px 0 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `:host` do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way to do it is to include this in your project global style.scss

```
app-instruction mat-expansion-panel.trigger-panel {
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding:0;
}
```

}

- app-instruction => your component selector in the component.ts file.
- mat-expansion-panel => selector for mat-expansion-panel.
- .trigger-panel => is a css class I included on the mat-expansion-panel to select only this one in the component.html file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me.

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header {
   padding: 0px 16px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

### for @angular/material version +10

You need to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` property into your @Component decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class myApp{}
```

Then this will work

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Note that ::ng-deep and /deep/ will not work on the new version of angular/material as @nicholaschris says

Comment: is there a reason why you would choose this over a global style?

Comment: This answer is not bad but not good enough. If you wish to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` you need to make component selector in css file before overwriting material angular component styles

Answer (score -4):

You can easily remove parent padding.

```
<div class="removePadding">
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of item.children" class="testingSmall">
      <h3 matLine>{{item.label}}</h3>
   </mat-list-item>
</div>

.removePadding{
   margin: 0 -24px -16px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting workaround, but that kind of thing can easily become a nightmare to maintain if you do that frequently. I would never accept that as a legit answer to this question, but it could be used as a desperate last resort