# How can I extend or overwrite component decorators in Angular Material 2?

Tags: angular-material2

I am nesting a `<mat-nav-list>` inside of a `<mat-expansion-panel>` component. At runtime, Angular Material 2 is creating html, in my specific case:

```
<div class="mat-expansion-panel-body">...</div>
```

Which also is getting styles assigned to it. I am unable to overwrite these styles using the component style sheet like I normally would.

Looking through the source, I am seeing this:

```
/node_modules/@angular/material/esm2015/expansion.js

MatExpansionPanel.decorators = [
{ type: Component, args: [{styles: [".mat-expansion-panel{transition:box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);box-sizing:content-box;display:block;margin:0;transition:margin 225ms cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)}.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]){box-shadow:0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12)}.mat-expansion-panel-content{overflow:hidden}.mat-expansion-panel-body{margin:0 24px 16px;overflow:auto}
...
```

I'm sure this isn't the exact code that is creating the component, but it does contain the css I would like to override:

```
...
.mat-expansion-panel-body{margin:0 24px 16px;overflow:auto}
...
```

How can I modify the decorator to remove the margin?
Here is what my `.ts` file looks like so far:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './my-selector.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-selector.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {...}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could take credit for the solution that seems to work, but [here is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689249/expansion-panel-from-material-angular-4) with a similar problem.

I was able to remove the margin like this:

**my-template.component.html**

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let foo of bar" class="my-sidenav">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        ...
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-nav-list>   
        <mat-list-item>...</mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**my-component.component.scss**

```
/deep/ .my-sidenav {
    .mat-expansion-panel-body {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```